# Count occurences of a pattern in SQL Server column

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I have a `varchar` column in SQL Server 2012 with 3-letter patterns that are concatenated, like this value:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(MAX) = 'POKPOKPOKHRSPOKPOKPOKPOKPOKPOIHEFHEFPOKPOHHRTHRT'
```

I need a query to search and count the occurrences of the pattern `POK` in that string. The trick is, all `POK` that are together must be counted as one. So, in the string above there are 3 "chains" of `POK`:

```
POKPOKPOK, interrupted by a HRS
POKPOKPOKPOKPOK, interrupted by a POI
POK, interrupted by a POH
```

So, my desired result is 3. If I use the following query, I get 9, that are the total POKs in string, which is not what I need.

```
SELECT (LEN(@str) - LEN(REPLACE(@str, 'POK', '')))/LEN('POK')
```

I think I need some sort of regexp to isolate the POKs and then count, but couldn't find a way to apply that in SQL Server. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really not something that you want to do in SQL.  But you can.  Here is one method to reduce the adjacent `'POK'`s to a single POK:

```
select replace(replace(@str, 'POK', '<POK>'), 'POK><', '')
```

Well, this actually creates a `'<POK>'`, but that is fine for our purposes.

Now, you can search in that:

```
select (len(replace(replace(@str, 'POK', '<POK>'), 'POK><', '')) -
        len(replace(replace(replace(@str, 'POK', '<POK>'), 'POK><', ''), 'POK', ''))
       ) / 3
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/15553) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Thanks, right what I needed. But why I should avoid this? I will put this on a user-defined function to use it in a query with thousands of rows with cells like the example. This will lock my table or something?

Comment: @dtc . . . These string operations are relatively expensive.  There may be a better way to represent and process whatever you are trying to do.